# Does Hibernate adjusting java.util.date (milliseconds) when I retrieve it from the db based on machine time?

Tags: java, hibernate

So we use Hibernate for Object-relational mapping and we have a Student.java (POJO) and a registrationDate (`java.util.date`). We save the student object with this date '`2012-01-05 10:00:00`' and when we look at the db it looks right as we save it.

The issue is when we get it back from the db (`student.getRegistrationDate`) instead of returning us the right milliseconds in GMT it returns us a modified milliseconds based on our time zone (our time zone -3, the wrong date is '`2012-01-05 13:00:00`' ). Now this is not the the normal behavior of java.util.date because it doesn't hold time Zone information, so I'm worried if actually Hibernate is adjusting the milliseconds in the date object to match the server local time or it could be something else ?.

Note: I get the date by using `date.getTime` not with `date.ToString`.

Comment: 1.) What column type is Hibernate using? 2.) Use JodaTime instead of Java's built-in date/time. It is much less painful and works correctly more often.

Comment: What database are you using? How is your date column defined in the database?

Comment: Are you running "Microsoft SQL Server"?

Comment: Im using MySQL, the column type is datetime.

Comment: @cdeszaq thanks for the suggestion, we are trying to move to it soon. But for now we are trying to debug this issue with the java date.

Comment: @Jimmy, how did you specify the mapping? Annotation or xml snippet would be helpful (but see my answer about using java.sql.Timestamp if possible) otherwize you will have to write your own implementation of  org.hibernate.usertype.UserType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion happens to the timezone application is running into. As you already know the work-around. Check this - http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForNon-defaultTimeZone.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use it as a Timestamp use java.sql.Timestamp instead of java.util.Date (which assumes Zulu time), which will properly take care of time zone.

Or you might try joda Time but with Hibernate and JodaTime, you might need a slight bit of work see [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html)

Comment: i know how to change it to make it work but this is what i want an answer for: Does Hibernate adjusting java.util.date (milliseconds) when retrive it from the db based on machine time?

Comment: What is the value you see int the DB itself? The "correction" could have happened either while the date was being serialized or being read back.

Comment: the date in the data base is the right one. the problem happen when i get it back.